# no let's encrypt renewal with reverse-proxy in ispconfig3

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, certbot, ispconfig

I am running an ISPConfig 3 server with apache. To get HTTPS i use the certbot of let's encrypt. ISPConfig supports cert generation which is working for various cites.

One site runs locally on a different port (as it is a complex system).
To reach it, i added a new site in ISPConfig and configured apache as a reverse proxy as shown below. 
The site is up an running, but unable to renew the certificates via certbot (does not work only for this site).

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off

<Proxy *>
     Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://my.domain.com:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://my.domain.com:8080
```

I guess the problem is the unreachability of the challenge folder (/acme/.well-known/acme-challenge)

How to configure apache as reverse proxy that it is able to renew its certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem here: the proxy endpoint doesn't have the same webroot and cannot serve the `.well-known` directory correctly, which means Let's Encrypt fails to find it.

The trick is to skip the proxying for the well-known URL, using something like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/518439). In my case, it was simply a matter of adding this line:

```
ProxyPass /.well-known/ !
```

which will disable the proxying for the certbot directory.

Good luck!

Comment: add it before ProxyPass / http://my.domain.com:8080